# Serial Comprehension in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, optimization, list-comprehension

Say one wants to run some kind of comparison on a list of combinations, for example:

```
combs []     r = [r]
combs (x:xs) r = combs xs (x:r) ++ combs xs r

answer = minimumBy (\a b -> compare (length . compress $ a) 
                                    (length . compress $ b)) list 

  where compress = 
           ...something complicated involving values external to the list.


*Main> combs "ABCD" [] --Imagine a larger list of larger combinations.
["DCBA","CBA","DBA","BA","DCA","CA","DA","A",
 "DCB","CB","DB","B","DC","C","D",""]
```

(The actual list would be a more complicated construction of combinations of strings, but in a similar vain, and any `x` would not offer insight into the adequacy of the total combination)

If the list gets quite large, would it be more efficient to somehow update one result as we construct and discard the inadequate combinations, rather than calling the comparison on a value representing the whole list?

e.g., (pseudo)

```
loop = do c <- nextComb
       if c > r then c else r
       loop
```

And how could that be done in Haskell? Or would Haskell's compiler optimize the `answer` value by discarding elements of the list automatically? Or something else altogether that I may be missing?

Comment: How about some type signatures?

Comment: @leftaroundabout `*Main> :t combs => combs :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]; *Main> :t answer => answer :: Integer` ;)

Comment: Are you looking specifically for the fastest way to get `answer`? Because that's just `sum [1..4]`. The pattern you are using is a fold, but there's no general way to fold over an entire list without generating the entire list. This is the fold invocation: `foldl' (\acc x -> max acc (sum x)) 0 $ combs [1..4] []` replacing your `answer` definition. Your entire combs function is a little weird. When is it useful for anything else than `combs x []`?

Comment: @kqr Thanks, I didn't think of the fold idea -- would `answer` be the same efficiency as the fold? As I explained in the question, combs is an example. The actual list would be a more complicated construction of combinations of strings, searching for a minimum length. But I think the idea may be similar.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could state your real problem, since optimisations are *very* dependent on what assumptions one can make about the data. When we don't know what problem you are trying to solve, we can't find the optimal solution either. The "optimal" solution to the problem you have stated here is `answer = sum [1..4]`, but I have a feeling that doesn't help you.

Comment: @kqr Thank you for your comments. Does my update help?

Answer (score 3):

In your example, inadequate combinations wouldn't be discarded, because `map sum` forces them to be fully evaluated. But if comparsion function needs only shallow repr of combinations, there is no reason why Haskell lazyness shouldn't work:

```
-- many combinations are evaluated only "of 1 elem depth"
answer = maximum . combs [1..4] $ []
```

Think about heuristics, which could help you to reduce enumeration:

```
combs (x:xs) r
    | x > 0     = combs xs (x:r) ++ combs xs r
    | otherwise = combs xs r
```

Keeping some information about discarded elements may be useful for it:

```
-- or combs discarded (x:xs) r = ...
combs least (x:xs) r
    | x < least  = combs x xs r
    | x == least = ...
    | otherwise  = ...
```

One more idea - accumulating more than one resulting list:

```
combs (x:xs) negatives positives
    | x < 0     = (nns ++ ns, ps)
    | otherwise = (ns, pps ++ ps)
  where
    (ns, ps) = combs xs negatives positives
    (nns, _) = combs xs (x:negatives) positives
    (_, pps) = combs xs negatives (x:positives)
```

You can find a lot of ideas about optimization of such permutational-exponential algorithms in the exellent book by Richard Bird ["Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design"](http://amzn.com/0521513383).

However, in real world using lazy Haskell list structure may easily become a bottleneck. Consider using more efficient structures, for example [Seq](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html) from `containers` package.

Comment: In your "combs least" example, I'm not sure how comparing `least` to `x` could help, since I would need to compare `least` to the total combination. In my actual list any `x` would not offer insight into the adequacy of the total combination. Is there a way to serialize the combinations?

Comment: @groovy my examples are meaningless, they're just illustrating ideas. What do you mean under "combinations serialization"? I suggested some approaches, and it is the maximum I can say from your question (see my answer edit also). You should probably reveal more details to get more helpful answer.

Comment: I appreciate your examples, they help me think about the process. By "serialize", I meant constructing the combinations and discarding the combinations one by one rather than performing a comparison on the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

If `compress` function is strictly *offline* (in the sense *absolutely unpredictable*, no assumptions about result could be made untill the entire combination is constructed) and the length of the source string is less or equal than 64 (I suspect it is, can't imagine > 2^64 Haskell lists on runtime :) The following "not Haskell way" solution could really help to reduce memory footprint:

```
import Data.Bits

-- see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/67087/44026
gosper :: Int64 -> Int64
gosper set = ...


answer source = go 1 0 (key 0)
  where
    go set r rV
        | set > limit = r
        | sV > rV     = go (gosper set) set sV
        | otherwise   = go (gosper set) r rV
      where
        sV = key set
    key = length . compress . comb
    comb set = [ch | (ch, i) <- (zip source [1..len]), testBit set i]
    limit = 2 ^ len - 1
    len = length source
```

Otherwise (`compress` is predictable basing on partial input), see my first first answer and think about heuristics...

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort to help, I'll have to study more to understand this answer. The "source string" is not actually a string but a list of tuples containing sequences that come from a string and indexes to their locations. The final comparison is made on compressed strings, which are constructed using the information in the tuples and the original string. So the idea needs to work for a list of any data-type from which combinations can be constructed.

Comment: @groovy what is unclear in my answer? I don't see anything difficult in it. `gosper` hack just generates permutations in bits of double word.

Comment: I am sure your answer is clear...I'm just a little slow :) ...I'm learning. Thank you for the ideas.